# Informatica post session command task

Tags: unix, informatica-powercenter

I'm trying to get my Informatica workflow to fail a session if it selected 0 source records.  I have come up with the following script to run as the Post-Session Success Command:

```
if [ $PM{Source Qualifier Name}@numAppliedRows == 0 ]
then
exit 2
else
exit 0
fi
```

where `{Source Qualifier Name}` is the name of my source qualifier.  When I look at the session log it looks as I would expect where the `$PM{Source Qualifier Name}@numAppliedRows` is replaced by the number of rows my source qualifier selected but it is still causing the session to fail even when this number is != 0.  The session log gives me the following error message:

> sh: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 1 : 'if' is not matched.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `/bin/sh` then you need to put a semi colon (`;`) after the square brackets.

```
if [ $PM{Source Qualifier Name}@numAppliedRows == 0 ]; then
exit 2
else
exit 0
fi
```